# ECMAScript-6 Audio Repeat Forever

Tags: javascript, audio, ecmascript-6

I want to make a audio player that will repeat forever without using any HTML at all. How can I do this in ECMAScript-6

Comment: The same way as you would do with ES5.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ES6, which defines no audio capabilities. Are you looking for the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't get what's the question,  but I found it kind of fun, so here is one solution, to loop an Audio forever, without using any HTML at all, and in a browser :

This uses the ability of browsers to run javascript inside SVG documents, and the WebAudioAPI to play sound out of the DOM :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<script>
const aCtx = new AudioContext();
fetch('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/agepbh2agnduknz/camera.mp3')
    .then(r=>r.arrayBuffer())
    .then(b=>aCtx.decodeAudioData(b))
    .then(data=>{
        const audio_buf = aCtx.createBufferSource();
        audio_buf.buffer = data;
        audio_buf.loop = true;
        audio_buf.connect(aCtx.destination);
        audio_buf.start(0);
        });
</script>
</svg>
```

Since stack-snippets will wrap everything inside an HTML document, here is an **[live plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bhmRg1OoL4F9CcsghZhC?p=preview)**.